# Starting a service from Job Scheduler in Android 8.0 (Oreo)

Tags: android, scheduling, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

I have to perform background data syncing to the server over the network regularly in my Android app. I am using a `JobScheduler` to perform this syncing. 
Can I start a service from the `onStartJob()` method in my class extending from `JobService`? Will it throw an `IllegalStateException` in Android 8.0 (Oreo) if the application is in background when the job runs?

Comment: Yes it will work on Android 8.0. But it will only work on lollipop and higher, if you want to make a job compatible all the way to API level 9 then you can use Firebase JobDispatcher (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)

Comment: There has been added something like `JobIntentSevice` [Here's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService) an reference.

Comment: @Nouman Bhatti : Yes I have checked Firebase Job Dispatcher too and both are similar except for the fact that FirebaseJobDispatcher is backward compatible to 9. But the question here is can I start a service in the JobService in onStartJob()? Because Android 8 has background restrictions where we cannot start a service when the app is in background and throws an IllegalStateException in such a case. Hence, if this job runs when the app is in background/killed then can we start a service from onStartJob? Will it throw an IllegalStateException in Android 8?

Comment: @DevAndroid why you want to start a service from dispatcher?

Comment: Why do you want to start a service from onStartJob() because we use JobScheduler in replacement of Service.

Comment: Because onStartJob runs on the main thread. So I will start a service to perform the network operation and return false from onStartJob to indicate that I need the wakelock to be held for a while longer

Comment: @WaleedAsim Do you think we should not start a service from a dispatcher/job scheduler?

Answer (score 2):

In Oreo, if you want to start service from JobScheduler `onStartjob()` you need to start **foreground** service with notification, because starting common background service will throw IllegalStateException

Answer (score -1):

Here is the library Android-Job (https://github.com/evernote/android-job) which solves background job scheduling issues across different Android versions, Oreo as well.

It executes Job on separate thread, so, most likely there is no need to start new/separate service. When executing job, library handles wake lock acquisition and holds it until job is finished.

Comment: Links to solutions are welcome as comments, but they do not provide a solution to the problem